# Repairing A Questyle QP2R

Tags: pcb

One of my friends purchased an used [qp2r](https://www.questyle.com/qp2r-en) from a local shop that was not turning on.

After thorough inspection and re-soldering quite a few components the device is working. However as I don't have the schematics it seems that some repair work on the PCB has been done.

Now here is the issue: while having a closer look at the PCB it seems there might be one component is missing. I assume, the component has been removed because the soldering marks are visible.

I have attached the pics of the qp2r PCB and also marked the location of the missing component.

What is the missing component and what function does it serve?
Have googled and found the picture of the PCB , it clearly shows the component, please advice as what could be that component , picture attached.[image]

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

[image: Pic 3]

[image: Pic 4]

Comment: Welcome! Looks like an unmounted option from factory. What’s not working?

Comment: That's not missing - it was never populated. Most likely for an option which that version of the device was not given.

Comment: Looks like optional flash memory pinout

Comment: nice DAP with balanced current mode audio amps.

Comment: Device is working fine , however while looking closely looks like the component was removed , not sure if it was never populated or something else that might degrade the performance without making it non functional. Any help suggestions are appreciated

Comment: No it doesn't look like the component was removed, it looks like the component was never populated in the factory. As evidence by the fact that the device is working, there's nothing Wichita needs to be done here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , was actually sceptical due to two reasons. One being the manufacturer website picture shows there is some component with metallic structure and secondly the PCB shows as if some smd component was removed . Just wanted to make sure that the performance is not degraded .